# Google Cloud, is it normal for Wordpress(click to deploy) install running more than 30 min?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have problem previously with my WordPress, so I delete that one and re-install another one using the same "Click to deploy Wordpress". But the installing time is longer than before and still running after 30 min. The website seems up but the information part(password, phpMyadmin password..etc) doesn't come out.

Is there something wrong with my setting? or is because I delete and re-install too many times? or what should I do to fix it?

Below is the image:
[the right side keep running more than 30 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2tzq.png)

Comment: Sounds like a question the team at Google Cloud support could assist you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce this issue and found a workaround that you can use for now until it is resolved.

Launching the Wordpress service creates two VMs- one temporary “coord” VM that handles the Wordpress build and deployment, and a main WordPress VM that hosts Wordpress. The issue appears to arise when the “coord” VM is not able to retrieve a startup script needed to complete the build, specifically:

https://storage.googleapis.com/c2d-install-scripts/startup-script.sh

As a result of this, the coord VM continually and unsuccessfully attempts to retrieve “startup-script.sh”, and the WordPress installation remains stalled.

The cause of this appears to be that the “coord” VM doesn’t receive an external address upon it’s creation, preventing it from retrieving “startup-script.sh”.

In order to resolve this issue you can assign the coord VM an external IP address, which allows it to retrieve “startup-script.sh”, which in turn allows it to complete the WordPress setup/deployment process.

**Instructions for the workaround**

1. In the Compute Engine “VM instances” page, click on the “coord” VM (the machine name should contain the string “coord”)
2. Click Edit
3. Click on the network interface for the machine
4. In the External IP drop-down select “Ephemeral”
5. Click on “Done”
6. Click on “Save” at the bottom of the page

This will provide it with an external IP address and allow it to access the resources it needs to complete the setup.

I’ve [reported this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/69098399) and you can click on the star icon to receive email notifications of any update on it.